# Azure VM DNS name label can not be set

Tags: azure, ubuntu, dns, virtual-machine

When creating a VM (Ubuntu) on Azure I always go to the `DNS name` link from the `Overview` page to set a `DNS name label`, like "myhost.westus.cloudapp.azure.com". Recently that host stopped working - I see the page with the settings greyed out and a message saying:

`This public IP address can't be updated because it is associated to the IP configuration 'ipconfig1', in the network interface 'abc123'.`

For VMs for which I have previously set a DNS name label I see the same message and again the label can not be changed.

Any ideas why I can not edit my `DNS name label`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Public IP then 'Dissociate'. Then go to Configuration, you should be able to add a DNS name label. Once it is done, go back to 'Overview' again then 'Associate'. You will need to find the NIC that you are wanting to attach the IP back to.

Comment: Hey thanks, this worked for me :)   One thing to note, is you have to go back and Associate it again after you've changed it in the Configuration page